# Is it OK to take time-off during the first week of a new job?

Tags: new-job, manager, new-hires, time-off

Is it OK to take time-Off during the first week of new job?

I just landed in a new job and this is the first week for me. Because of an unexpected situation I have to take Off on Friday of this week. Is it good to take time-off during the first week of new job? I don't have any projects assigned yet and I'm taking some online training and self-training. No formal work has been assigned to me yet.

Just wanted to know if this will create a bad image about me to my team and Supervisor.

Edit: Thank you all for the great answers. I got my leave approved from my Supervisor. I hope it doesn't make any bad image of me to him and I wish similar scenario doesn't happen in the future :)

Comment: Might be a good idea to try to delay it as soon as possible. Otherwise you're going to have to suck it up and tell your supervisor.

Comment: Just be sure to explain with a good reason on why. For example, maybe you just moved into the area and need to set up your living space and need a workday to set things up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Without a specific reason it does create a bad image.**

With specific reason I don't mean you owe your supervisor the explanation that your grandmother died but a reason such as:

- unforeseeable event in the family
- medical problem

Just make sure your supervisor knows that it is important and couldn't be planned for in advance.

The first few days/weeks at a job are usually unproductive so missing a day shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> *Just wanted to know if this will create a bad image about me to my team and Supervisor.*

Well, it should not be, for a single-day leave and if you don't intend to keep repeating that. People can have "emergencies", we essentially have no control over those.

Make sure you present your case to your manager and seek approval as early as possible. Also, so far I've considered "Because of an unexpected situation" to be an urgent and emergency one, not an "extended-weekend-trip-plan-to-sea-beach-with-buddies" that floated up on the group chat.

However, if that leave period is of significant length (more that 4-5 days), and not a medical or medical-related leave) - that may raise some eyebrows.

Comment: its just for 1 day

Answer (score 1):

It's all in how you explain the situation.

You need to go to your supervisor, and tell them the whole story and why it's so important you have that day off.

You have likely not accrued any vacation yet, so expect to owe the day, or accept a cut in pay for that week.

If your explanation is strong, and you commit to working extra to pay for that day (maybe the Saturday?), then it should send a good message instead of a bad one.

Comment: I have sent my request with explanation behind the need for day-off and waiting. Also I have 1 floating holiday that is available to use. I spoke with the HR to know about any leave policy before I decided to ask my supervisor. Keeping fingers crossed

Comment: @Rick Offer to owe the day anyways and offer to work another day or longer hours to make up for it.  That shows strong commitment to your job.

Comment: @TrevorD I'm failing to see the point. If i'm entitled to avail a leave and I have a real reason to avail it, why to offer extra hours? It's a leave , after all,

Comment: @SouravGhosh It makes it look like you want the job and want to work. If your worried about creating a bad image, then create a good one instead by showing how much you want to work for them.

Comment: @TrevorD I am very much interested in working, however, I don't want to follow "live to work" analogy, either. If I'm compensating, I'd prefer not applying for leave, i'm compensating for the time anyways. I'm not exactly opposing you, but for a fair assessment, just making sure not being unnecessarily "extra polite"  which is also not a good thing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Extra polite in the first week isn't a bad thing.  Are you on a probation? Usually 3 months?

Comment: I am not under probation. But I have no projects assigned. So there is no point in committing to work for extra hours since my Supervisor is also aware that I am not actively working on any project right now.

Comment: @Rick then your probably good to go.